# How to convert 6 photos to 360 panorama

Tags: python, image, opencv, panoramas

I have script that convert 6 pictures (up, left, bottom, right, front, back) to one panorama.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

up = cv2.imread('sides/up.jpg')
down = cv2.imread('sides/down.jpg')
left = cv2.imread('sides/left.jpg')
right = cv2.imread('sides/right.jpg')
front = cv2.imread('sides/front.jpg')
back = cv2.imread('sides/back.jpg')

height, width, _ = front.shape
if left.shape[0] != height or right.shape[0] != height or up.shape[1] != width or down.shape[1] != width or back.shape[1] != width:
    print("Размеры сторон не соответствуют")
    exit()

panorama_width = width * 4
panorama_height = height * 3
panorama = np.zeros((panorama_height, panorama_width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

panorama[height:height*2, width:width*2] = front
panorama[height:height*2, width*3:width*4] = back
panorama[0:height, width:width*2] = up
panorama[height*2:height*3, width:width*2] = down
panorama[height:height*2, 0:width] = left
panorama[height:height*2, width*2:width*3] = right

cv2.imwrite('panorama123.jpg', panorama)

cv2.imshow('Panorama', panorama)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This script create file with black squares. Is it possible to make this panorama seamless so that there are no empty areas? Thank you in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ounkv.png)

Already used "stitcher" from cv2, but it can't find common points between pictures.